# Raspberry pi wifi point

Tags: wifi, pi-4, hostapd

I have a hostapd running on my raspberry pi 4b on wlan0. I also have installed succesfully a usb wifi adapter. I can have wifi on the pi and send a wifi connection to a laptop or other device. My question is how can i send the wifi from my adapter to my hostapd so i can be on the internet on a other device thru my rpi?
If i connect a ethernet cable i can use wifi on other devices, only not with the wifi adapter.

sudo iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          
wlx3460f902843e  IEEE 802.11AC  ESSID:"bawi_ziggo_5g"  Nickname:"WIFI@RTL88X2BU"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.22 GHz  Access Point: 6C:5A:B0:BF:92:1F   
          Bit Rate:867 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/100  Signal level=46/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o wlan0  -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i wlx3460f902843e -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
suco iptables -I FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlx3460f902843e -j ACCEPT
```

**This presumes that the internet uplink is wlan0.** Otherwise switch the interface name in the `-t nat -I POSTROUTING` command.
This will take place immediately but will not persist across a reboot.

You may have to `apt install iptables` if that is not found.

If this does not work, edit into your question the output from:

```
sudo iptables --line-numbers -n -v -L
```

as it was *before* you did the above (so you will have to reboot, or else just do it and save it first).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. It actually already worked when i did this:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o wlx3460f902843e -j MASQUERADE
```

Is there any way to permanently change these setting, so a reboot will not change it?

Comment: Create a script and define a systemd service file for it. Or add those two lines to `/etc/rc.local`